# Dropdown that enable/disable button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a dropdown menu that enable/disable button, and I'm following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752257/jquery-disable-enable-button-dropdown-selections)

but it's 4 years old and the function doesn't seems to work on my xhtml page.

Any help would be appropriated

Comment: What have you tried? Change `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` to `.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: I love this SO-driven development :) Can we see what wrong with your `xhtml` page?

Comment: both, but nothing is working.

Comment: the fiddle in your example still works, did you upgrade your jQuery version?

Comment: It's jquery/1.9.1 @Freez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/txrkrgms/

using .prop() method on the button you like when the select is .change().

```
$("select").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "on")
        $("button").prop("disable", false);
    else
        $("button").prop("disable", true);
});
```

Hope is what you are searching for.

Comment: remember to change the selector to match yours, as you can see in the fiddle, it's working. make sure your jQuery is running well also

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id='ddlToggle'>
    <option Value='1'>ON</option>
    <option Value='0'>OFF</option>
</select>
<input type='button' id='btn1' Value='Hello' />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#ddlToggle").on("change", function(){
    $("#btn1").prop("disable", $(this).val() == "0");
});
```